# Android Google Play Services Incorrect Configuration

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services

Morning all hope you can help as I've failed to find an answer to an issue I'm experiencing using the Google Play Services from GitHub with Unity. I've followed different guides including the official but am unable to get a successful authentication when testing.

I've recently used the Minimal Sample and created a new Application on Developer Console; package name matches, SH1 key matches, application ID submitted and gmail account added to tester list but when testing I'm greeted with a message advising something is incorrectly configured or user hasn't been added to tester list. I've tried on 2 separate apps and different devices with different users and all have failed. The error does advise to check logs but when checking Apps logs I find nothing to help or pin point where the issue may be.

Can anyone offer any advise on what I can do to fix this issue?

Thanks in Advance,
Adam﻿

Answer (score 0):

Found out that the service Test Fairy was changing the SH1 of the app.